# Python 3.7.2 folder cannot be located in /Library/Python

Tags: python, macos

I want to edit some of the modules I installed for Python 3. I went to /Library/Python and the only folder I found was 2.7. This is not the folder Python 3 runs on. I tested this by installing a module in the Python 2.7 folder by using pip and trying to run it in python 3 (it does not work). Where is the folder?

I use macOS

Comment: Leaving aside the question of where the folder is, you *definitely* shouldn't be editing files in that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into the terminal app, and type `which python3`. This will output the path where python3 is located.

But as Daniel says in a comment, it's really not recommended to edit anything in modules that you install.

Comment: This gives me the path to the framework but not the modules

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. The path is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages

Alternatively, type this into terminal:
 `find / -name (INSERT NAME OF MODULE)`